# libGDX: Removing Iterator after specific time

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Following https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending%20the%20Simple%20Game
How can I make it so that the iter.remove(); will happen every second more or less? I mean, from the moment a new iter appear the program will count a second more or less and call iter.remove();.

Here is the code from the link that use the Iterator:

```
    Iterator<Rectangle> iter = raindrops.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Rectangle raindrop = iter.next();
        raindrop.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (raindrop.y + 64 < 0)
            iter.remove();
        if (raindrop.overlaps(bucket)) {
            dropsGathered++;
            dropSound.play();
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
```

By the way, can I use the same solution to create a seconds stopper? At the moment I created a stopper to my game, 60 seconds game time. For the stopper to work I basically created an int stopper = 60; and as long that the game run the number will decrement by 1. Problem is it decrement too fast!

Timer method:

```
decreaseTime(int minus){
// timer is equal to 60    
    timer -= minus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the render method, delta is used to keep track of time (in a sense - it shows the amount of time the last frame took to get rendered, so it might not always constant) and you should be using delta since different devices have different frame rates. The reason your stopper goes too fast is because the render loop is being called so many times a second (for example, on a 30 fps device, it is called 30 times a second).

So if you wanted to do some action every 5 seconds, you could do something like:

```
 int timeTracker = 0; // Do this outside render since you don't want to keep setting it to 0.

 // Inside render
 if (timeTracker >= 5){
      timeTracker = 0;
      // Do something
 } else {
      timeTracker += delta;
 }
```

This is a simple and not so elegant solution, but easy to implement and should fit your needs.

If you want each raindrop to disappear a second after its creation, you will need to implement a raindrop class to keep track of each raindrop and the amount of time it has be created for. Then you can loop through the raindrops and dispose the ones who have been created for more than one second. Again, not the most elegant, but easy to implement.

First create a raindrop class and then you can do something like this. I can't do all your work for you, but at this point you should get the point and figure it out.

```
    Iterator<Raindrop> iter = raindrops.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Raindrop raindrop = iter.next();
        if (raindrop.timeSinceCreation >= 1){
            raindrop.dispose();
        } else {
            raindrop.incrementTimer(delta);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I changed the number in the condition to 1 and in the "Do something" I called the timer\stopper's method "decreaseTime(1)", but it didn't do anything…

Comment: The code is in the render method.  The timer method that I mentioned is used for a timer that will be put in the game for the player. I edited the code with the timer method.

Comment: Ok, I got the hold on, on how to make the drop disappear. But I still don't get the timer part. I tried entering the timer method to the condition that create a new drop, and it worked, the timer went down properly every second, but every time that I click on a drop the timer stops and continue after the drop disappear…